# Login Session in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session

this is my code in my login page..i need to allow only **Users** in my database to login..A User can be Admin who can access to some links in my site..so others cant access i have assigned Admin to my **Role** id as R2
Users can view my all my Report except the StaffReport...so if i am Admin i will use the Admin Username and password
this is my code on my login.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require_once("mysqlconn.php");

    $dbconn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


    mysql_select_db($database, $dbconn);

    $uusername= $_POST['uusername'];
    $upassword= $_POST['upassword'];

    // build query
    $qry = "Select * from Users where u_username='$uusername' and " .
        "u_password=PASSWORD('$upassword')";

    // execute query
    $result = mysql_query($qry) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
    {


        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);          

        .
        $_SESSION['userno'] = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['roleno'] = $row['role_id'];

        header("Location: ./index.php"); 

        // stop execution of this page
        exit;
    }
    else
    {

        header("Location: ./LoginForm.php"); 

        exit;
    }

    mysql_close($dbconn);

?>
```

in my fun.in.php i have this

```
<?php
    // start the session - this has to be done in all scripts that use $_SESSION array
    session_start();    
    DEFINE("ADMIN_ROLE", "R2");
    // function to check if the user has logged in. If user has loged in then this function
    // returns a true
    function Has_Session()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['userno']) or 
            $_SESSION['userno'] == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Declare cleaning function 
    function clean_it ($string_variable)
    { 
        $string_variable = addslashes(trim($string_variable)); 

        return $string_variable; 
    } 

    function IsAdministrator()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['roleid']) AND 
            $_SESSION['roleid'] == ADMIN_ROLE
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function printErrorMessage($message)
    {
        echo "<center><table id='form-table'><th>Access Error</th>" .
            "<tr><td><b>$message</b></td></tr></table></center>";

    }


?>
```

The problem When i try to login eg John which assign as Adminstartor(R2) i cant login..no error displayed but it returns me to my Loginform

Comment: Wow. SQL injection, session fixation and XSS vulnerabilities all in the same short bit of code! Not to mention the fact it doesn't do the one thing it's supposed to. Maybe you should add some debugging in place of the redirect.

Comment: maybe there are 2 jhon's with the same password so this doesn't pass: if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)

Comment: maybe it redirects you to index.php and index.php redirects you back to login.php (we dont know the code of index.php)